# Range Filter not working in django rest does not react at all when filtered

Tags: django, rest

Range Filter not working in django rest  does not react at all when filtered

View

```
class MDShopListView(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = smartphone.objects.all()
        filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
        filterset_class = ShoppFilter
        def get(self,request):
    
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            serializer=MDShopListSerializer(queryset,many=True)
            
        
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the queryset, with [**`self.filter_queryset(…)`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#filter_querysetself-queryset):

```
class MDShopListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = smartphone.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ShoppFilter
    
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer=MDShopListSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But actually overriding `get(…)` is *not* necessary, since now it does almost exactly what a `ListAPIView` does by default, except that you do not paginate. Indeed, a [`ListAPIView` is defined as [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.12.2/rest_framework/generics.py#L193-L199):

> ```
> class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
>                   GenericAPIView):
>     """
>     Concrete view for listing a queryset.
>     """
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

and the `.list(…)` method is defined in the [`ListModelMixin` as [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d635bc9c71b6cf84d137a68610ae2e628f8b62b3/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33-L46):

> ```
>     def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
>         if page is not None:
>             serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
>             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
>
>         serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
>         return Response(serializer.data)
> ```

You thus can define this as:

```
class MDShopListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = smartphone.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ShoppFilter
    # specify the serializer ↓
    serializer_class = MDShopListSerializer
```